# How to encrypt file from Python using AWS KMS server side encryption

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3

I am fairly new to python. Need some help. This is what I need.

- We want to look for the file in directory, if file exist and size of the file is not zero bytes, I want to encrypt the file using AWS KMS encryption and upload it to bucket.
- If file doesn't exist then raise an exception
- If file exist but the file is zero bytes then raise exception.

Below is the code I could come up with but I am sure there is better way to write this and need your help. One thing I couldn't achieve is the encryption.

```
import os
import sys
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config
import configparser
import re
import os.path
import glob

## Initialize the Parameters
def initconfig(input):

    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read_file(open( 'CONFIG_AIRBILLING.conf'))
    print('Code Name is :'+ input)
    global REMOTE_DIR,ACCESS_KEY_ID,ACCESS_SECRET_KEY,BUCKET_NAME,TARGET_DIR,FILENAME,SRC_DIR,File,FILEPATH
    ACCESS_KEY_ID = config.get('ACCESS', 'ACCESS_KEY_ID')
    print('ACCESS_ID_IS:'+ ACCESS_KEY_ID)
    ACCESS_SECRET_KEY = config.get('ACCESS', 'ACCESS_SECRET_KEY')
    BUCKET_NAME = config.get('ACCESS', 'BUCKET_NAME')
    SRC_DIR = config.get(input, 'SRC_DIR')
    FILENAME = config.get(input, 'FILENAME')
    FILENAME=FILENAME+'*.txt'
    FILEPATH=SRC_DIR+'\\'+FILENAME
    print('File Path is:'+FILEPATH)
    TARGET_DIR = config.get(input, 'TARGET_DIR')
    File='demo.txt'


## This function will make sure file exist in Source directory
def readstatus():
    print('Startibg')
    try:
        with open(FILEPATH,'r') as f:
            f.closed
            result='True'
            movefiles(result)
    except (Exception) as e:
        print('***Error:File Not Found or Accessible***')
        result='False*'
        raise e


## This function will move the files to AWS S3 bucket
def movefiles(result):
    if result=='True':
        s3 = boto3.resource(
            's3',
            aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            aws_secret_access_key=ACCESS_SECRET_KEY,
            config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')
        )
        s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).put_object(Key=TARGET_DIR + '/' + File, Body=File)
        print('***File Moved***')


    print("Done")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(len(sys.argv))
    initconfig(sys.argv[1])
    print(sys.argv)
    readstatus()
#initconfig(input=input())
#readstatus()
```

Comment: AWS supports both client-side encryption and server-side encryption. You should read [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingEncryption.html) and decide which you want, as the implementation will be different. _Hint:_ unless you have a _specific reason_ to prefer client-side encryption, use server-side encryption.

Comment: See 'ServerSideEncryption' and https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.put_object

Comment: Thank you.. How to make sure data is encrypted in transit?